# Using home PC as a computational machine when needed, remotely

Tags: linux, ssh, arch-linux, wake-on-lan, thin-client

I have a notebook and a more powerful home machine both running Arch Linux. What I want is when needed send a wol package onto the home machine from the notebook, then launch a remote X session and use all my home pc's resources.

So barely this should look like a normal home pc usage (using its CPU, RAM) and the notebook is used like a display. This solves two problems at once: configuration synchronization in the way that I will have only one work setup (no need to setup the same thing twice, heavy IDE packages stay on home pc without consuming notebook's space) and using pc's SSD, CPU and RAM to make everything work smooth and fast.

However, it seems to me that using the notebook as a remote display over network won't be that smooth and fast. But still, even if that won't work I consider using home machine as a resource supplier through cli.

Is it possible? I've found the information about how to setup wol and I know the SSH basics but don't know where should I go next, what to google and how to organize it.

Comment: It is a software recommendation when I say you can use PCanywhere or VNC. These can access your machine remotely and let you do the work. [VNC](https://www.realvnc.com/download/viewer/) works on Linux and I'm not sure of PCanywhere

Comment: Unfortunately, `In May 2014 Symantec announced the end of life for Symantec pcAnywhere`, so I'll take a look at VNC, seems like it supports SSH sessions (wikipedia states that the general protocol is not safe so another security layer needs to be used). But the SSH session requires a running pc and I'm not sure if it is possible to wake it up and then connect to it via SSH (because user needs to log in etc.) or a VPN tunnel. Although this could be probably done with the router, I use Mikrotik.

Comment: May be we can [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access)

Comment: I joined the room.

Comment: Let me know how you implement your VNC. Just interested to know